# How to make a if statement so this prolog code can sen a message when there is a conflict int the n coloring problem

Tags: prolog

I'd like to print a message when there is some conflict in the map coloring
but can't figure out the if/else statements in this language

```
color(Map,Colors,Coloring) :-
        find_regions(Map,[],Regions), 
        color_all(Regions,Colors,Coloring), 
        \+ conflict(Map,Coloring). 
 
color_all([R|Rs],Colors,[[R,C]|A]) :- 
        member(C,Colors), 
        color_all(Rs,Colors,A). 


color_all([],_,[]). 
 
 
conflict(Map,Coloring) :-
        member([R1,C],Coloring), 
        member([R2,C],Coloring), 
        adjacent(R1,R2,Map).


find_regions([],R,R). 
find_regions([[X,Y]|S], R,A) :- 
     (member(X,R) ->  
        (member(Y,R) -> find_regions(S,R,A) ; find_regions(S,[Y|R],A)) ; 
           (member(Y,R) -> find_regions
```

Answer (score 1):

A conflict in the coloring is detected by doing checking all region pairs:

```
conflict(Map,Coloring) :-
        member([R1,C],Coloring), 
        member([R2,C],Coloring), 
        adjacent(R1,R2,Map).
```

If this succeeds, then region (really vertex) `R1` and `R2` are "adjacent" and have the same color, which is disallowed.

As this was called as

```
\+ conflict(Map,Coloring).
```

in

```
color(Map,Colors,Coloring)
```

another coloring is attempted with a redo of

```
color_all(Regions,Colors,Coloring)
```

The easiest way to give information about what's going on in `\+ conflict(Map,Coloring).` is

```
conflict(Map,Coloring) :-
        member([R1,C],Coloring), 
        member([R2,C],Coloring), 
        adjacent(R1,R2,Map),
        format("Regions ~q and ~q have both color ~q and are adjacent!~n",[R1,R2,C]).
```

Alternatively you could make the conflict visible outside the predicate:

```
conflict(Map,Coloring,R1,R2,C) :-
        member([R1,C],Coloring), 
        member([R2,C],Coloring), 
        adjacent(R1,R2,Map).
```

And then do this in the caller:

```
color(Map,Colors,Coloring) :-
        find_regions(Map,[],Regions), 
        color_all(Regions,Colors,Coloring), 
        \+ 
          ( conflict(Map,Coloring,R1,R2,C),
            format("Regions ~q and ~q have both color ~q and are adjacent!~n",[R1,R2,C])
          ).
```